# FileReplace in F-Sharp

Tags: file, replace, f#

I need to make a program in fsharp which replaces all occurrences of a string "needle" in an input text file with another string "replace". A nice solution to this problem has already been posted here:

[F# - fileReplace, overwriting words in txt, but when running it overwrites exisiting content in txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40380851/f-filereplace-overwriting-words-in-txt-but-when-running-it-overwrites-exisi)

Unfortunately, my program has to explicitly use the functions **System.IO.File.OpenText**, **ReadLine** and **WriteLine** which the aforementioned solution does not.

I cannot see how this can be done in an effective and non-convoluted way. Problem is that if you use **System.IO.File.OpenText** to open the input file, then you cannot both read and write to the file. But we need to write in order to replace the aforementioned occurrences of the needle argument. So what to do then? do you need to make another temporary file, open it as write-only and then perform the WriteLine on it with input equal to **system.IO.FILe.OpenText.readLine**? This seems too complicated.

I will add the specific assignment below if anyone needs it:

> Make a program in F#
>
> ```
>  fileReplace : string -> needle : string -> replace: string -> unit
> ```
>
> which replaces all occurrences of the needle argument with the replace argument in the file with name filename. The solution must as a minimum use the functions **System.IO.File.OpenText**, **ReadLine** and **WriteLine** to access the files.
>
> A short test must be included and a short description of the solution with arguments for larger design choices taken to reach the given solution

Comment: How about opening the file, read the contents, close it, replace the necessary strings in memory, then write back the contents.

Comment: One possible solution would be to read the whole file into memory, then perform the replacement, then write the result back to the file.

Comment: i thought about reading one line at time using Readline and saving each resulting string into an array. we can then afterwards perform the replace method on each string in the array and, finally, create a new file with the same name as the old and begin writing each string to this using Writeline. Was this what you were thinking?

Comment: Thank you for being upfront about the fact that this is an assignment; it helps us know the best way to help you. (I.e., don't post the code, but give you hints toward the answer so you can figure it out yourself). I have seen many "please help me with my homework" questions on Stack Overflow, and rarely do they say right up front that it's a homework assignment (though it's usually quite obvious). +1 for being upfront about it, which makes this a MUCH better question than it would have been if you hadn't mentioned that fact.

Answer (score 1):

To help you a bit without giving out the entire answer, the following example shows a bit how to use the functions mentioned in the assignment to work with files.

It implements a simple code snippet that reads data from one text file line by line and writes the data (without replacing anything) to another file:

```
open System.IO

let fileIn = File.OpenText("C:\\Temp\\test-in.txt")
let fileOut = File.CreateText("C:\\Temp\\test-out.txt")

let mutable line = fileIn.ReadLine()
while line <> null do
  fileOut.WriteLine(line)
  line <- fileIn.ReadLine()

fileIn.Close()
fileOut.Close()
```

The tricky thing here is that `ReadLine` returns `null` at the end of the file. Dealing with this in a nice functional way is not very nice, so I just used mutable variable and `while` loop, but you could do the same using recursion or list comprehensions.

This reads data from one file and writes it line-by-line into another file. This avoids the need to read everything into memory, but it means you need two files, because you cannot (using those functions) overwrite the file while you're reading it.

To solve your problem, you could either create a temp file and then replace the original one with the new file, or you can read all data into memory before doing the replacing.